# Implement Android Media3 player with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

TLDR: I need to play some videos that have protected content, so I need to setup DRM (Digital Right Management) and at the moment there's no Stable Flutter plugin that handles this subject properly, but the native players (iOS, Android...) do! So I'm trying to Implement the latest version of ExoPlayer (Media3) in my Flutter project and I'm no that experience to do so and I'm looking for some guidance.

[Android Media3 doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media3/getting-started/migration-guide)

[DRM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management)

[Flutter custom platform-specific code](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab)

I tried looking up some Flutter packages that uses Explayer.v2

Answer (score 0):

Isn't https://pub.dev/packages/better_player stable? The documentation says in the feature list:

✔️ DRM support (token, Widevine, FairPlay EZDRM).

Comment: I've tried it but I found it super laggy for 4k videos, and on top of that I have some custom DRM configs to do which better_player doesn't give me a way to do them and it also uses exoplayerV2 which is discontinued